# Why does my code run the goto loop two more times than it should?

Tags: loops, goto

This a code exercise I have to do for my C programming class, and it doesn't work. I tried to find the problem, but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone shed some light on this problem?
Here's the code(don't mind the Korean):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    char mun;
    while(1)
    {
    re:
        printf("알파벳 입력 :"); /* basically says "type an alphabet" */
        scanf_s("%c", &mun, sizeof(mun));
        cnt++;

        if (mun != 'Q')
        {
            printf("찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요.\n"); /* "Not the alphabet we need, type another alphabet" */
            goto re;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("총 %d회 실행하여 알파벳을 찾았습니다.\n", cnt); /* "Found the alphabet after %d tries."*/
            printf("찾은 알파벳은 대소 문자 구별 없이 \'Q\'입니다.\n"); /* "The said alphabet is q, either uppercase or lowercase. "/
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's hard to explain, so here's the result that it's supposed to print:

```
알파벳 입력 : 3
찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요.

알파벳 입력 : k
찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요.

알파벳 입력 : Q
총 3회 실행하여 알파벳을 찾았습니다.
찾은 알파벳은 대소 문자 구별 없이 'Q'입니다.
```

But instead it just runs the goto loop two more times, like:

```
알파벳 입력 :3
찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요.
알파벳 입력 :찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요. /* see here? */
알파벳 입력 :k
찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요.
알파벳 입력 :찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요.
알파벳 입력 :Q
총 5회 실행하여 알파벳을 찾았습니다.
찾은 알파벳은 대소 문자 구별 없이 'Q'입니다.
알파벳 입력 :찾는 알파벳이 아닙니다. 알파벳을 다시 입력하세요. /* it also runs the goto loop after the 
알파벳 입력 :
```

Please, someone help me!

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to use a debugger to step through the code to see where you've made an error in your logic. A debugger is one of the best tools available to a programmer, and it's never too early to learn how to use it.

Comment: I ran the code through the Visual Studio debugger and it didn't report any problems. Maybe it's because it's a logical error that I'm experiencing? Or are there any more debuggers that could report what the problem is?

Comment: You need to step through the code line by line. The debugger doesn't *report* problems. It allows you to set a breakpoint and then step through each line to see exactly what's happening; you can examine the contents of variables and trace the exact flow of execution to figure out your logic errors.